# After some downtime, most of my site ranks normally in Google, but one subsection stopped ranking. What is happening there and how can I change it?

Tags: seo, google

Bing ranks me normally. There are no spam measures taken against my site (I asked them). All urls stayed the same. It's been about 2 months

Answer (score 3):

Have you registered with Google webmaster account? if no then do it now and verify your ownership.

Submit your website there and wait for couple of days, if Google crawler finding some issues with that sub folder; they will display there.

It happen some time when your website goes down; Google takes quick action to downgrade the rankings but once it is up again; it re-position those websites.

There are many reasons behind non-index problem in your website; if you can share your website url, it will be easier for us to share more insight.

Comment: It's been about 2 months since my site is back to normal, but rankings have not come back; they continue to dip. I have Google Webmaster account, all is normal there. I am not a spammer, and I don't do low quality content. So I am really confused as to what is happening here. Site url: http://www.caravanistan.com. Not ranking url http://www.caravanistan.com/transport/ and everything below that. All help more than welcome!

Comment: Recently i visited your web page (transport) page and here what i think why it is not ranking:
- Very less content on that page (i strongly recommend add some useful content in that category.
- I found 6 backlinks for this page but non other than your website itself.
- As of now; you need to work on improving content and backlinks and you will start getting ranks

Comment: Thanks, seems like it was simply the Google dance, it started ranking again soon after that. But it taught me to get rid of Google more and focus on attracting traffic in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check google webmaster tools.
2. Fix errors.
3. Add more and more content.
4. Return to 1.